# NFC REQUIRED on app, is it going to be visible to users who dont have it?

Tags: android, nfc

Say my app has NFC REQUIRED (set on manifest), will my app be shown on google play to users who don't have NFC on their device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because Google Filters the Apps in the Store:

More about how Google filters: [Filters on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

If you have set the required attribute to `true` then Google Play will filter the app and it will be displayed to only devices that have NFC feature.

Otherwise make it `false` if your app don't only depend on NFC and check the feature dynamically as

```
if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC)) {
            // has NFC. Use NFC feature here
        }
```